# Authentication in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux

When the user successfully logs in, the user must be re-directed into another page. This page is not accessible if you are not logged in.

Here is the login form code

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    handleFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = e.target.elements.user.value;
        const password = e.target.elements.password.value;

        this.props.onAuth(user, password);

    };

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log(this.props.successLogin)

    };
```

Here is the mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps function

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        error: state.error,
        successLogin: state.token
    }
};

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAuth: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password))
    }
};
```

And here is its action

```
export const authSuccess = token => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS,
        token: token
    }
};
```

Here is the code in the login page

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (

    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (

        rest.auth
            ? <Component {...props}/>
            :
            <Redirect to='/'/>

    )}/>
);
```

Here is the routing link

```
<PrivateRoute path="/Main_Page" exact component={Main_Page} auth={this.props.isAuthenticated}/>
```

And its connect

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return {

        isAuthenticated: state.token !== null

    };

};
```

The console.log prints twice. ones **null** and ones with the actual **token**. 
My question is what is wrong in the logic that is making the `console.log(this.props.successLogin)` print ones null then the token, and vice versa when logging out ?
The challenge this poses is my page ends up re-directed to ``` <Redirect to='/'/>``, although I am authenticated, and I can access all the ```PrivateRoute path`

Comment: are you using something like `redux-thunk`? or `redux-promise-middleware`?  In this case maybe the first action returns default value `null` and then when it's updated again, nothing wrong with redux, I think.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia yes I am using redux-thunk. That causes a slight issue because my page ends up re-directed to `<Redirect to='/'/>``, although I am authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it

```
  <Route exact path="/"render={() => (this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
                                     <Redirect to="/Main_Page"/>) : (
                                     <Log_in_Page/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if user successfully authenticated or nor before rendering

```
  {this.props.isAuthenticated && <PrivateRoute path="/Main_Page" exact component={Main_Page} auth={this.props.isAuthenticated}/>}
```

Comment: where do you add this check ?

Comment: before you main page load, you will have to check that user is authenticated or not.